# Node js, mongoose Sort data from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

Let's say I have a car collection. Now I would like to get cars that are red and have a mileage less than 100k km. Should I get all cars from database and make a function to filter cars or maybe mongoose have a function to filter this cars?

At the end, I would like to random 5 cars from this filter and display same cars to 5 different users in this same time. How should i do that?

I think this picture explains everything

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNtb.png

Comment: Please update the question with sample dataset (collection docs) and expected output in order for us to help out better. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass filters directly into the mongoose query.

```
const cars = await Collection.find({
    Color: "red",
    Mileage: {
        $lt: 100
    }
}).limit(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use a mongoose query, like:

```
model.find({ color: red }).where('mileage').lt(100000);
```

[mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) (for more options like limit or sort)

and then just take a random function to filter the values again.

P.S. maybe there is a better solution in perspective of performance